Why are random variables determined only by their even moments?
I have been working on some problems which involve determining when is it that random variables are uniquely determined by the sequence of their moments. Because of this I stumbled into Carleman's condition which states that a random variable is determined by its moments if
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty m_{2k}^{-1/2k}=\infty$$
where $m_{2k}$ is the $2k$-th moment of the random variable.
I can't understand why are even moments the determining moments.
I do understand why odd moments aren't enough. For example, every symmetric random variable with mean $0$ has odd moments equal to $0$. Is there some intuitive way of understanding this? Or even if the reason is too technical, why does this happen?

It’s not that the even moments are the determining factor, it’s simply the moments used in Carleman’s condition. Intuitively, you could say that the moments simply tell how the distribution behaves, e.g., the first and second moment give a description of the mean and variance.

In fact, apart from the trivial case of a distribution concentrated at $0$, no distribution is determined by its even moments. For any other $X$, the even moments of $-X$ or $|X|$ are the same as those of $X$, but not all of these have the same distribution.

Thanks for the observation @NicholasBurbank. So then my question would be, why isn't the order of magnitud of odd moments taken into account in Carleman's condition?

I'm not sure what you're asking here. The even moments give bounds on the odd moments, since $|EX^{2k-1}|\leq 1+EX^{2k}$. So if you bound the rate of growth of the even moments (as in Carleman's condition), you also bound the rate of growth of the odd moments. For obvious reasons, as you note, it's not the case that the odd moments bound the even moments. However, you could restate Carleman's condition just using the odd absolute moments $E|X|^{2k+1}$, if you wanted. Or just using moments $m_{10k}$, or appropriately weighted $E|X|^p$ for $p$ prime, or many other things you could dream up....

Yes that was exactly what I was trying to ask. Thank you!
How does one derive that inequality though?
